# When is it appropriate to neglect the arguments of the function?

Tags: functions

Consider the probability density function of the normal distribution which [can be written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution):

$$f(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

Does the symbol $\mid$ imply that it is acceptable to write the function $f(x)$? When is it appropriate to insert this symbol between the arguments of the function? Is this purely a subjective decision based on which arguments are most important or are there rules governing this?

Comment: The vertical bar, $\mid$, usually means that a "given" follows. This means that $f(x\mid \mu,\sigma^2)$ says $f(x)$ given a particular mean, $\mu$, and variance, $\sigma^2$. The $x$ is an argument, and the $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are parameters. Parameters can often be shown as subscripts or superscripts, and can also be omitted if assumed contextually.

Comment: It is a convention often followed in inference, when we emphasize that the distribution is indexed by the (unknown) parameters $\mu,\sigma^2$. That is, for different values of the parameters, the form of the density varies. $f$ here is a function of $x$, so it is perfectly valid to write $f(x)=...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bar in $$f(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$
indicates that if we have a normal distribution with a " given " mean and standard deviation, then the density function is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$

Most authors do not use this notation and use $N(\mu, \sigma)$ to emphasize that the distribution is normal with the given mean and standard deviation.

You may as well write  $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$$
without any problems.